# .NET Assembly Loading with Strong Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to load the assemblies (example my service layer assemblies) into my MVC application from a location (directory) other than the Bin folder (I dont want to register in GAC)

Can I have a strong name common across all my assemblies I use in my application. Any Disadvantages of having a common strong name for all assemblies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Assembly.LoadFromFile() with any path. Could be a bit tricky though if the assembly to load requires other libraries which are stored in your default bin folder. It normally works, but I've also seen problems arising there (especially also in unit tests etc.).

What do you mean by "one strong name"? Using the same keyfile for all assemblies? Yes, that's definitely acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply PMF. I use Spring.NET to inject the assembly into the MVC application. To be precise, I inject the Login Service in my Login Controller using the application context.My application works only if I add reference of the LoginService Dll or copy the login service manually to my bin folder or register in GAC. In this scenario how do i load it from different location.

Comment: I don't have any experience in MVC, so I'm not aware of the requirements for such a service. But what's the problem with copying it to the bin folder? You can do that in a post-build step as well.